# Why System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception does not follow standard naming convention for interfaces in .NET?

Tags: c#, interface, naming-conventions

Generally Interface name should be start with `I` 
example `IClonable`, `IListSource`, `IXmlSerializable`, `ISupportInitializeNotification`, `ISupportInitialize`, `ISerializable`, But here i found a Interface definition:

```
public interface _Exception { }
```

Why is the interface name defined as _Exception? why not IException? Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: Where did you see that interface declaration?

Comment: Part of the .net framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices._exception(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It sounds like a [class interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fcadw4a(v=vs.110).aspx) for exposing a managed type to COM interop.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the author :]

Seems that somebody was following another naming convention... Does this interface name make any problem for you?

**EDIT**:

If you are referring to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices._exception%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface it seems that there is just another naming convention applied inside `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace

Comment: Is it a public interface?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development/dp/0321545613/ref=sr_1_7/275-0151373-6576247?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1401095923&sr=1-7&keywords=Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework), which explains the problems they had when writting the first versions of the framework; at the beggining of the .Net framework lifecycle there were lots of discussions about guidelines (naming conventions, interfaces vs abstract classes, etc).

That is why "old namespaces" such as the [Interop services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Runtime.InteropServices%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) contain implementations that are against the rules that you can find today, basically those rules where learned and implemented while implementing the code itself!

The .Net framework still has old legacy code that cannot be changed because of the implications it would have in old applications.

I believe there was some more info in [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/CLR-Via-4th-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1401096146&sr=1-1&keywords=clr%20via%20c#) as well, but not too sure now.

Answer (score 0):

The author should be able to answer this ;-)

I bet this has to do with the fact that this interface is meant to expose the members of the `Exception` class via COM/unmanaged code! There may be other naming conventions in the COM-/unmanaged world.

Generally you're right - in the .NET world interface names should start with a capital `i`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's because the only thing this interface is good for is to contain all methods and properties of a certain type for use in COM.

> This interface is for access to managed classes from unmanaged code and should not be called from managed code.